# Refactoring portfolio without affecting live site and pushing daily?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, netlify

My portfolio website is hosted on netlify and is linked to its respective github repo. Any push to master will automatically deploy the changes.
Now, I wish to change the layout of my portfolio to match a template I found, however I've already started applying to jobs so I don't want to affect the existing portfolio until I'm done reworking it.

Now you may be saying branch > make changes > merge.

Right, my problem with that is, I want to push daily for github contribution tracker. It would take me several days to finish all the changes I wish to make and I don't want to break my streak. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a new branch called 'dev'. Just check everything in on that branch (so you don't lose you daily contribution tracker since you can just check everything in daily on the dev branch). And when everything is done, you can just create a PR from dev to master. This is actually called the 'Gitflow', you can read more here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: Wow I've never heard of this before, just skimmed it and it would definitely solve my problem, Thank you kindly

Comment: Nobody cares about your github contribution tracker? And why do you think pushes to the separate branch won't be tracked?

Comment: I've heard potential employers may care? Anddd uhhh because I'm uninformed I guess..

Comment: I am a potential employer and it's always nice but not needed to see the progress tracking. Open source projects are not the only factor in becoming a software engineer so gaps in time is expected on the tracker